# Send SMS on mobile number from odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, mobile, sms, odoo-10, sms-gateway

I want to send SMS on any mobile number from Odoo 10. For this, I created a wizard on a button. Now, I have no idea how to send sms to any mobile number. Anyone can give suggestion about this Odoo feature?

Comment: There are apps on odoo app store for sending sms. You can check relevant app from there.

Comment: For odoo10 i didn't find any app, which is freely available for me. If you can know about that, than suggest me URL for app.

Comment: You can download any free apps and then migrate it in odoo 10

Comment: I found Twilio_SMS app, but it shows error while installing for odoo10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these odoo modules:

[sms_gateway](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/sms_gateway/)

Or

[sms_frame](http://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/sms_frame/)